# Can't get innerHTML of the h1 tag after JSON ajax load from Java Server

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, rest

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/users",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(people) {
    people.forEach(function(person) {
      usersDiv.innerHTML += '<div>'+
      '<h1>' + person.username + '</h1>'+
      '<button class="send-message">Write message</button>'+
      '</div>'; },
  error: function(err) {
    alert("blad + error" );
  },
  contentType: "application/json"
    }).done(function() {
      $(".send-message").click(function() {
        var that = $(this);
        var parentOfThat = that.parent();
        var nameOfTheUser = String(parentOfThat.find("h1").textContent); 
      });
    )
```

This code works perfectly fine. It populates userDiv with h1 paragraf with each person name from the json object. **When I want to retrieve the name of the h1 innerHTML, it produces undefined.** I tried almost every method, from text() to html() and so on.

Comment: Can you read what I wrote? I wrote that I have tried every method from innerHTML, text(), html() to textContect ...

Comment: can you try `var nameOfTheUser = $(this).prev().text();`?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using find("h1").eq(0).text() or find("h1:first").text() to ensure that only one element is retrieved?

Comment: I tried it. I actually use class to retrieve this: find(".user-name") So this is not a problem, my friend.

Comment: So the selector works fine? Do you have an HTML Element or not? If so, does the returning element have the jquery extension or  should you extend it object with $()?

Answer (score 0):

Change to this

```
contentType: "application/json"
    }).done(function() {
      $(".send-message").click(function() {
         var nameOfUser = $(this).prev('h1').text();
         //alert(nameOfUser);
      });
    )
```

Here is the JSFiddle to show [how this change works](http://jsfiddle.net/oa65j0m5/2/)

Comment: Yes. I tried it. It produces empty string. I also tried the same thing as you post in JSfiddle. I've got no trouble. I only got this trouble only while retrieving json data from server.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Problem solved! I actually had one div more there! So instead of

```
String(parentOfThat.find("h1").textContent)
```

I had to change it to:

```
String(parentOfThat.parent().find("h1").textContent)
```